# How can I fit power law model in MATLAB in a loop until a specified condition is met?

Tags: matlab, loops, curve-fitting

So I have two vectors: *x* and *y*, each with 1800 elements. What I need to do is given below:

1. Fit a power law of the form *y* = *ax^b* between *x* and *y* considering all the elements in *x* and *y* (i.e., all 1800 elements).
2. Calculate *ypredicted* from the obtained parameters *a* and *b* of power law.
3. Calculate deviation (= (*ypredicted* - *y*)/*y* *100) by comparing the last element of *ypredicted* and *y*.
4. Again fit power law between *x* and *y*, but this time use only the elements 1 to 1799 of both *x* and *y*. Repeat steps 2 and 3.
5. Repeat step 4 for the elements 1 to 1798, and so on, until for elements 1 to 50 of both *x* and *y*.

At the end, I need all the values of *x* used in the loop that yielded deviation between 2.98% and 3.02%.

Please help in this regard. Please comment if more information is needed to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%example data
a = 2;
b = 1.45;
x = linspace(0,1E4,1800);
y = a*x.^b;
y = y.*(1+randn(1,1800)*0.02);
plot(x,y);

f = @(x,p) p(1)*x.^p(2); %function
sqerr = @(x,y,p) sum((y-f(x,p)).^2); %sum of squared errors
p = [1,1]; %starting conditions
vals=[];
for ct = 1800:-1:50
    p = fminsearch(@(p) sqerr(x(1:ct),y(1:ct),p),p); %fit
    dev = (f(x(ct),p)-y(ct))/y(ct); %devation (can be negative as well!)
    if dev>0.0298&&dev<0.0302
        vals=[vals,ct];
    end
end
```

Comment: The code works as expected! Thanks! However, could you help me understand the use of _sqerr_ function and _fminsearch_ function?

Comment: Is it also possible to add a statement in the code so that I can see what are the values of deviations obtained at each value of _vals_?

Comment: @user3024069 `sqerr` is, as the comment suggests, the sum of the squares of the terms error, which is the function you want minimised. It is written as an [anonymous function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). You can see the documentation for a description of [`fminsearch`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).

Comment: @user3024069 If the answer solves your issue, please consider marking it as Accepted.